# Linux/Bash ARP Lookups

Tags: bash, networking, mac-address, sniffing, arp

Very simply I am looking to get a list of all devices on a specific subnet for the purpose of identifying their mac address to find all devices by a particular vendor on that network.

Presently I am using `nmap` to accomplish this, however it makes me specify a host, example `10.0.0.0/24`, which is good for `10.0.0.0` addresses, however I would like to be able to get the `10.0.1.0` devices and `10.1.1.0` devices as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
nmap -TAggressive -n -sS -p80 10.0.0.0/24 &>/dev/null
nmap -TAggressive -n -sS -p80 10.0.1.0/24 &>/dev/null
nmap -TAggressive -n -sS -p80 10.1.1.0/24 &>/dev/null
arp -an | awk 'BEGIN {print "MAC               IP"}{++i;print $4, $2} END { print i,"hosts found"}' | tr -d '()'
```

Comment: You forgot to do `++i` in the action statement of `awk`. `print i` in the `END` statement won't do anything without it.

Comment: Why not a single call to nmap? `nmap -Tblah ... 10.0.0.0/24 10.0.1.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 &> /dev/null`

Comment: I actually got better then that with a different nMap command that would list off all the devices it found, and not take very long either.  I will post that here when I get the chance.